# Validating sqlite db formatting in python, if db is in the form of a String/StringIO object

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

If there is an SQLite database in the form of a String or StringIO object, is there a Python module that provides a quick and straightforward way to validate the formatting of the database? Most modules seem to require you to pass a reference to a file to open a db, and in the scenario I'm dealing with, no file exists, so I would like to validate the formatting of the database directly through its contents. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you even have an SQL database into a string? Do you have a valid reason for that?

Comment: The data is created within the application by a third party, and no file is available.

Answer (score 3):

The `sqlite` database offers a in-memory option itself. Use `:memory:` as the filename to create it.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10c8f76c0>
>>> list(conn.execute('SELECT * FROM foo'))
[]
>>> list(conn.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master'))
[(u'foo',)]
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')  # a reconnect gives a new empty database
>>> list(conn.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master'))
[]
```

No file is created for the connection, and closing python will close the in-memory database and the schema and all data in it is discarded.

Your only other option is to use a temporary filename; `sqlite` insists on handling the file itself in it's entirety. You *cannot* pass in a file-like object, it *must* be a filename or the string `:memory:`.

Comment: Hi, Martijn - to clarify, I want the db to exist only as the String or StringIO object within a python framework/program, rather than creating any more instances of the db, or using any sqlite functionality. I'd like to validate it using only python/python modules.

Comment: @winshade: expanded. You have no such option. If you want to validate the schema, the `:mem:` database is *exactly* what you want though.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, I'll give it a shot. Also, it appears that the option may be ':memory:' rather than ':mem:'.